# How to `git diff --name-only master` with rugged?

Tags: ruby, libgit2, rugged

In Ruby, using the [rugged gem](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged), how does one do the equivalent of the following?

`%x(git diff --name-only master)`

I need to list changed files that are either staged or unstaged.

Comment: rugged's README has an example of listing the [files that changed](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged#diffs) by going through the deltas, which include the paths. What isn't working for you there?

Comment: @carlos-martín-nieto, thanks. I read the README but I couldn't get it to work since I didn't "already have a diff object" yet and I wasn't sure how to get one that included both staged and unstaged changes.

Comment: @carlos-martín-nieto, I edited my question to explicitly mentioned staged and unstaged files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with:

```
files0 = %x(git diff --name-only master).split($RS)

require 'rugged'
files1 = []
changed = %i(index_modified index_new worktree_modified worktree_new)
repo = Rugged::Repository.new(Dir.pwd)
repo.status { |f, d| files1 << f unless (changed & d).empty? }

puts(files0.sort == files1.sort ? "PASS" : "FAIL")
```